# detect whether variable contains letters or numbers javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, numbers, character

I've been looking on the internet but couldn't find a proper solution to my problem.

I have two use inputs. One is Age. The other is Name.

Age must be a number. Name must be a word, containing only characters.

```
if(age==number $$ name == characters){

    // do something

}else{

    // do something else

}
```

I tried:

```
if(Math.floor(num) == num $$ Math.floor(name) != name){

    // do something

}else{

    // do something else

}
```

But no luck whastsoever.

If you know how to do this could you let me know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ca you define "only characters" ?

Comment: What letters ? Any alphabet ? Is π allowed ? Or `-' ? Or spaces like in many names ?

Comment: Letters from a-z and spaces. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex solution is probably the simplest given that your input will be strings anyway.

Try this:

```
if (/^\d+$/.test(age) && /^\D+$/.test(name)) {...}
```

The main difference with the ones posted above is in the `^` and `$`; these will make sure that the string containts *only* the specified character, as opposed to them containing at least one.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```
if (+age==age && name!=+name) {
```

It checks that both conditions are verified :

- age strictly contains a number
- name isn't a number

But it's hard to define a strict rule for a name. Here's a name in my country : `"Dupé d'Egïe"`

Supposing you'd want to accept for the name only "Letters from a-z and spaces" (which is probably a bad idea), then you may do

```
if (+age==age && /^[a-z ]+$/.test(name)) {
```

To test if age contains only digits and name contains no digit, you may do

```
if (/^\d+$/.test(age) && /^\D+$/.test(name)) {
```

Comment: When I typed John123 into name input box it worked so that's a probem

Comment: @DennisCallanan That's why I asked you what you call a character. many names contains chars like `é`, `-`, ` `, `'`, etc.

Comment: Ok, sorry baout that, any other ideas?

Comment: I see what you mean. Would you know how to say. if(name contains no numbers && age contains only numbers)

Comment: I was able to type John123 into name and 456h into age using your latest edit

Answer (score 0):

You could use the javascript function parseInt(value), if the result is NaN, It's not a number

```
if(parseInt("54")) {
    console.log("It's a number");
} else {
    console.log("It's not");
}
```